# Need Sed or any script to remove whitespace between characters and replace with underscores

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I have an large language .ini file whose lines look like this:

```
CC MY APPS=My aplications
CC MY APPLICATION SETTINGS TITLE=My Settings
```

I need to remove all whitespaces between CC and = and replace with underscores like this:

```
CC_MY_APPS=My aplications
CC_APPLICATION_SETTINGS_TITLE=My Settings
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="="}{gsub(/ /,"_",$1)}1' file
CC_MY_APPS=My aplications
CC_MY_APPLICATION_SETTINGS_TITLE=My Settings
```

Alternatively if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -F"=" -ane '$F[0].gsub!(/\s+/,"_");puts $F.join("=")' file
```

Comment: might be better to use `$;.inspect` in the join method instead of hardcoding the separator string.

Answer (score 0):

A perl way to do it, very similar to kurumi's solution in Ruby :

```
perl -i.orig -F= -ane '$F[0]=~s/\s+/_/g;print join"=",@F' file.ini
```

The original file will be saved into `file.ini.orig`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if your values don't contain a '=', you could try:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\s+(?=.*=)/_/g' file.ini
```

using a look-ahead.